# Select only rows with "True" pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have to do, maybe a simple thing, but I completely don't know how. I have some code:

```
data = df_new.assign(result=df_new['text'].isin(df_oryginal['text']).astype(str))
df_same = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and the output is:

```
                                                     text  name          index  result
0                                               some text  filename        0    False
1                                               some text  filename        1    True
2                                               some text  filename        2    False
3                                               some text  filename        3    False
4                                               some text  filename        4    True
...                                                  ...          ...    ...    ...
36213                                           some text  filename    36213    False
36214                                           some text  filename    36214    False
36215                                           some text  filename    36215    True
```

Now I would like select only these rows where df_same['result'] == True, but I don't know how.
I have looked all over Google... Please help me, thank you in advance for your answer :)

Comment: use `df[df['result']]` or ``df.loc[df['result']]``

Comment: Did you read the docs? Docs on indexing for both [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html), and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) are extensive.  Maybe you were not familiar with the term indexing?  In that case, going through the quick start guide should get you familiarised with most common terminology.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 8):

```
result_df= df.loc[df['result']==True]
```

result_df will contain the rows which satisfies your condition having result True

Comment: In case you have a boolean column, you can also just write `result_df= df.loc[df['result']]`.